# Compiling the Requests library

Tags: python, android, ios, python-requests, kivy

If I were to use the Requests library in a python kivy app and compile the app for android and iOS, would it still be able to perform its requests, or will it just crash because it's on the wrong operating system or something?

If it would crash, how could I solve this problem or go about finding a solution?

Comment: How would you compile a Python app for iOS?

Comment: @ScottHunter https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-ios.html this is the tutorial I was going to use alongside youtube tutorials from more experienced people! Also, I know I shouldn't be using python and kivy but I decided to give myself a bit of a challenge as it supported development for iOS. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Well, any python library that you use in kivy will work on both `android` and `ios` or any other platform (`windows` & `mac`). As all the python library are compiled and handled by kivy so you need not worry about the platform for that. If you are using any platform-specific thing then that might not work on other platforms, but python libraries like requests work fine on any platform you use.